# object variable and first element (foreach)

Tags: php, magento, variables, object, foreach

I've got variable in magento:

```
$collection = Mage::helper('catalog/product_compare')->getItemCollection();
```

Now to call function from only first element I'm using **foreach**:

```
foreach ($collection as $id => $comparing_product) {
    $some_id = $comparing_product->getId();
    break;
}
```

**Is it possible to call this function without foreach?** 
**$id** gives me **10**, but I can't use **$comparing_product[0]** (or **[10]**) (this is not working, cause this variable is object, right?)

Answer (score 0):

Try this (I use this on ZF2 collections):

```
$first = $collection->first();
$id = $first->getId();
```

Or

```
$first = reset($collection);
$id = $first->getId();
```

Comment: Almost good :) I found solution: instead first(): <pre>getFirstItem()</pre>

Answer (score 0):

I found solution:

```
$collection->getFirstItem()
```